# Правильная реализация "связанных" списков (группировка)

Tags: c#

Возможно просто не правильно формулирую вопрос (или название), но...

Есть список экземпляров классов, у каждого из которых есть переменная, содержащая порядковый номер, и название группы, в которой они находятся, а так-же другие данные.

```
List<MyClass> MyClasses = new List<MyClass>();
public MyClass{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужен так-же список групп, условно

```
List<MyGroup> MyGroups = new List<MyGroup>();
public MyGroup{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    List<MyClass> ContainedClasses { get; set;} = new List<MyClass>();
    ...
}
```

И это всё должно быть "соединено", с желательно, как можно меньшими затратами ресурсов.
Те, список `MyClasses` - главный, при этом, у нас есть еще и и список групп, который формируется на основе списка классов, при этом у него есть и собственные свойства, и он хранит не отдельные экземпляры объектов, а "ссылки" на них, таким образом если изменять объект, находя его в группе, то он измениться списке классов, и наоборот.

Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: возьмите бумажку и ручку и нарисуйте классы, что вам надо, и отношения между ними. Сейчас, например, видно, что поле `GroupName` относится к группе, а не классу, а значит в классе ему делать нечего.

Comment: примерно знаю, что ответить, но возможно не так понимаю сути вопроса. опишите вопрос более понятно

Comment: @tym32167, вы меня, наверное не правильно поняли. Мне необходимо,что-бы все группы и элементы были независимы друг-от-друга, что-бы я мог получить объект класса, понять из какой он группы, и изменить ее. Или из группы получить номер класса, и не обращаюсь больше по группе изменить его по Id. То, что вы пытаетесь мне описать (Список групп, в каждой группе список классов), у меня уже есть.

Comment: что то не понят ваш вопрос..точнее чего вы хотите, но насколько понял - ответил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать ссылки

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> itr = new List<int>(){ 1,2,3 };
            List<MyClass> mc = new List<MyClass>();
            mc.Add(new MyClass(ref itr,"asd"));
            itr.Remove(2);
            mc[0].nums.ForEach(e=> {Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());});
            // вывод будет 1 3
        }

    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public List<int> nums;
        public string title;

        public MyClass(){}

        public MyClass(ref List<int> n, string t)
        {
            nums = n;
            title = t;
        }
    }
```